# php sql inserted double, once empty once with values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

my code worked a bit earlier today, but now all of a sudden it stopped working and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is my code to insert values in to my DB:

```
public function ingave()
{
    $db = new Db();
    if(isset($this->m_sDatum)){
    $sql="insert into tblingave (datum, tijdstip, duur, intensiteit, stress)
        values(
            '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_sDatum)."',
            '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_sTijdstip)."',
            '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_iDuur)."',
            '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_iIntensiteit)."',                     
            '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_iStress)."'
            )
            ";
    }
    $db->conn->query($sql);
    echo $sql;
}
```

If I run this I get the error that my `$sql` (on the line of `$db->conn->query($sql);`) is unidentified.

If I run it without the `if(isset($this-m_sDatum))` statement it echo's 2 sql's and inserts 2 rows in the DB.

In the first row all the values are empty and in the second row all the normal values are inserted.

If I run my code like this:

```
public function ingave()
{
    $db = new Db();
    $sql="" ;
    if(isset($this->m_sDatum)){
    $sql="insert into tblingave (datum, tijdstip, duur, intensiteit, stress)
        values(
            '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_sDatum)."',
            '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_sTijdstip)."',
            '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_iDuur)."',
            '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_iIntensiteit)."',                     
            '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_iStress)."'
            )
            ";
    }
    $db->conn->query($sql);
    echo $sql;
}
```

it says that my query is empty, but the `echo $sql;` shows

```sql
insert into tblingave (datum, tijdstip, duur, intensiteit, stress) values( '2014-05-20', '01:07', '8', '3', '3' )
```

and it also comes in to the db.

What could be the problem of these errors and double inserts?

Comment: A guess: You're calling the function `ingave()` twice, once where `$this->m_sDatum` is not set, and then once when it is.

Comment: this is the code where i call the function.: http://pastebin.com/V2A66GBW     I wouldn't know where I call the function a second time ?

Comment: I think that it's firing up your `ingave()` function with the added `$i->ingave();` - Try to comment that out, see if it works and doesn't add it twice. Because it seems you may be calling the function itself.

Comment: if I don't write $i->ingave(); How does my document know then that it has to run this function ? 
The function is written in a class
and the $i->ingave() is in the documente of the form itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably put the `$db->conn->query($sql);` in your if block. Then use `empty` for checking. `isset` is useful however, will execute your MySQL script even if $this->m_sDatum is NULL.

```
public function ingave()
{
    $db = new Db();
    if(!empty($this->m_sDatum)){
    $sql="insert into tblingave (datum, tijdstip, duur, intensiteit, stress)
        values(
            '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_sDatum)."',
            '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_sTijdstip)."',
            '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_iDuur)."',
            '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_iIntensiteit)."',                     
            '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_iStress)."'
            )
            ";
    $db->conn->query($sql);
    echo $sql;
    }

}
```

Comment: I had tried it with putting the $db->conn->query($sql); in the if block but then it just did nothing. But i've just copied your code and now it works ... could that realy be because of the !empty ? 
Thank you very much !!!

Comment: yes, i don't know how the function ingave is being called twice but with that solution, !empty will check if $this->m_sDatum is NOT EMPTY so if it has value, it will execute your mysql